# How to add side drawer? [Nativescript + Angular]

Tags: android, angularjs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In main module I added this:

```
import {SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES} from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";
...
declarations: [
        SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES,
        AppComponent,
        ...AppComponents
]
```

xml part for app.component.html:

```
<RadSideDrawer [drawerLocation]="currentLocation" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
        <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

When I try to run it I get error:

> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method onCreateView failed
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nativescript/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.js,
>   line: 91, column: 39
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'RadSideDrawer.initOldDrawer',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nativescript/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.js',
>   line: 91, column: 40  Frame: function:'RadSideDrawer._createUI',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nativescript/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.js',
>   line: 147, column: 18     Frame: function:'View._onContextChanged',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nativescript/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view.js',
>   line: 202, column: 14     Frame: function:'View._onAttached',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.nativescript/files/app/tns_modules/ui/core/view.js',
>   line: 1

Anyone know what is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

- Make this import:

`import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular';`

- Add it to your imports:

`imports: [
    NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
    ...
  ]`

Now, your side drawer should work fine.

Comment: I tried so many ways to make it work, but this is the only way it did. The official docs are bad and not organized.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to fix an issue like this is to use NativeScript Sidekick. Choose to create a new project. One of the templates features a SideDrawer.